# "exited, segmentation fault"

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

In the following code we have an error saying "exited, segmentation fault" when I try to enter in an integer for x.

If x was declared as a global variable, why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x;

int a(int &x)
{
  int y = x--;
  int z = x - 2;

  if (y == 0)
  {
    return (5*4-6*a(z));
  }else if (z == 0)
  {
    return (5*a(y)-6*4);
  }else if (y == 1)
  {
    return (5*9-6*a(z));
  }else if (z == 1)
  {
    return (5*a(y)-6*9);
  }else{
    return (5*(a(y))-6*(a(z)));
  }
}

int main() 
{
  cout << "Enter an integer value for x: ";
  cin >> x; 
  a(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a non-mutable value as a mutable reference? You never use the result of the mutation. Just use a regular argument. You also declare `x` as global while using it within `main()`, meaning it's really a local variable to that function.

Comment: What value caused the seg fault?

Comment: My money is on a smurf up in the exit condition for the recursion and in  the global case the program goes boom.

Comment: `clang` to the rescue: `warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]` This is why you compile with `-Wall`.

Comment: Yeah. Every case calls `a`. Game over. Nothing to do with using a global. For reasons of [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) the error is more visible with the global than whatever else you used.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation for undefined behavior? Just let that to rest and avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The all paths of execution of the function `a` calls the function `a`, so you are doing *an infinite recursion*.

```
  if (y == 0)
  {
    return (5*4-6*a(z)); // a is called here
  }else if (z == 0)
  {
    return (5*a(y)-6*4); // a is called here
  }else if (y == 1)
  {
    return (5*9-6*a(z)); // a is called here
  }else if (z == 1)
  {
    return (5*a(y)-6*9); // a is called here
  }else{
    return (5*(a(y))-6*(a(z))); // a is called here
  }
```

An infinite recursion can use the stack up and cause Segmentation Fault. (it may not cause that: for example when *tail call optimizaiton* is done)